# lightning data service : picklist field not showing

Tags: picklist, lightning-data-service

Is picklist not supported in lightning data service when using with lightning:input

`<lightning:input type="text" label="Description" value="{!v.simpleRecord.Description__c}" />`

I need to use Lightning data service but picklist field is not showing?
Any inputs?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `lightning:inputField`?

Comment: are you using `lightning:recordViewForm` or `force:recordData`?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal: i am using force:recordData

Comment: @KeithC : it(lightning:inputField) does not render any field when used with force:recordData.

Comment: If you use `force:recordData` you have to fetch picklist values from apex. Use `lightning:recordViewForm` instead.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_load_record.htm

Comment: @PranayJaiswal thanks pranay. Actually i was trying not to use server side controller. that's why i was trying to use force:recordData as it does not require controller.

Comment: You can achieve same with `lightning:recordViewForm `

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Need to save the record after filling the values using lightning:input

Comment: You can use `lightning:recordEditForm` if you want to save data and then you can use `lightning:inputField` as suggested above, which will get all the picklist values (if included in the record type) out of the box. Docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said, recordEditForm is you best bet. But if you need to get the picklist values separately, you can use the uiAPI to get that without Apex, but you need to provide a Record Type Id - so something like this worked for me to get values for a custom picklist field on Account

```
//Include Import Reference to Object Info and uiAPI
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

//Import object and field references = e.g. custom field for State Values
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import STATEOFREP_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.StateOfCoverage__c';

//Get the object info so I can lookup the Record Type Id I want
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    wireObject(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.objectInfo = result.data;
            const rtis = this.objectInfo.recordTypeInfos;
            this.accountRTID = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'KW - Member');
          } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
          }
    }

//Now look up my Picklist Values
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$accountRTID', fieldApiName: STATEOFREP_FIELD })
    stateOptions;
```

Then I have a getter to return those to the page

```
get stateOptionValues() {
    if (this.stateOptions.data) {
        return this.stateOptions.data.values;
    }
}
```

On the page it looks like this:

```
 <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" small-device-size="6">
                <lightning-combobox name="State"
                                    label="State of Representation"
                                    options={stateOptionValues}
                                    value={searchState}
                                    onchange={handleChangeSelectValue}>
                </lightning-combobox>
 </lightning-layout-item>
```